# MySQL Query to pSQL Query (Date to NULL)

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have a mySQL Query with dates like "0000-00-00 00:00:00". PostgreSQL does not accept this format. Is there a command which changes all those Dates to NULL?
I am migrating Data from a mySQL Database to a postgreSQL Database. What I currently want to do is to input the Data from the mySQL Database to postgres Database with the sql Dump. So I can start transforming the data in the targetdatabase.
My query looks like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "table_name";
```

```
CREATE TABLE "table_name" (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  version int NOT NULL,
  created_by varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  created_date timestamp(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  last_modified_by varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  last_modified_date timestamp(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT UK_AkademischerTitel_Name UNIQUE  (name)
)  ; 

INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (1,1,'admin','2016-02-13 23:00:00',NULL,'0000-00-00 00:00:00','Dr.')
```

Comment: How exactly is the data getting from MySQL to Postgres?  Can you add this information?

Comment: [This](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vkfGwB6okUJrciAVn4MckB/0) is your best option in PostgreSQL, structure wise as  `0000-00-00 00:00:00` isn't a valid date you should have never have used that format.

Comment: may be something like this since these would be more like nulls
update table table_name set created_date = null where created_date = "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

Comment: @RaymondNijland I already considered this option, but the data in the insert statement is much bigger than in the example so it would be a big effort to change all the values manually.

Comment: Well use a varchar then so you can insert 0000-00-00 00:00:00 and later update those values to NULL and alter the table to a datetime or timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Simply find and replace strings to solve this problem. 
If you are using Linux, open SQL file in vi/vim editor then find and replace this pattern using following way.

```
:0,$ s/'0000-00-00 00:00:00'/NULL/g
```

Above line we are searching from line 1(0) to the end($) finding pattern '0000-00-00 00:00:00' and replacing it with NULL globally means any number of occurrences in a line.